# How to select text in <p> elements that are between <hr> elements with Jquery and PhantomJS

Tags: jquery, phantomjs, element

I am looking to output the text from all elements between some 'hr' tags.

```
<hr>
<h2>i need this heading.</h2>
<p>i need this text.</p>
<p>and this one.</p>
<p>and also this one.</p>
<hr>
```

I have tried to use `$('hr:first').nextUntil('hr').text()` and output to a text file using fs.write, but the text is all on one line.  How can I do this and have line breaks on each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the output of this `fsString` where ever you were using that statement before to write it out. It will concatenate the individual text contents of each element found with the generic windows line end characters (`"\r\n"`). If you're using a different line end type then just substitute the `"\r\n"` for `"\n"` (typically *nix) or `"\r"` (typically older Mac OS), whatever is in use for the rest of your file.

```
var fsString = "";
$('hr:first').nextUntil('hr').each(function(i,o){
    fsString += $(o).text() + "\r\n";
});
```

Also, a neater way to do it is to add the line end characters to the existing elements and then get all of the text as you were doing before and use it in exactly the same way as you already were doing.

```
$('hr:first').nextUntil('hr').append("\r\n").text();
```

Comment: One can't simply use `fs.write` inside this call (because it is sandboxed). Just append to a string, it's fine. Just like NullPointer's answer. Then it would be the same code, but NullPointer has a description. Either add another (better) description to your answer or delete your answer. There is no need for essentially the same answer.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for pointing that out, I'm not familiar with `fs.write`.

Comment: Thank you, $('hr:first').nextUntil('hr').append("\r\n").text(); worked perfectly for my case.

Answer (score 1):

This method iterates through all elements between and including the hr elements (not sure about the last) and takes the text and puts then appends it to string `str`. It uses the `'\r\n'` for linefeed + newline in the string. After this code section you can write that string using fs.write.

```
var str = '';
$('hr:first').nextUntil('hr').each(function(i, e) {
    str += $(e).text() + '\r\n';
});
```